# How can I use in and not in operator in a single if condition

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

My problem is to find an element exists in  list1 or list2 or exists in both

```
if elemnt in list1 and not in list2:
```

#it says syntax error , not working

Comment: `if element in list1 and element not in list2:`

Comment: But this ain't working.

Comment: Found the answer and it goes like - if element in list1 and element not in list2:

Comment: these kind of problems you can break down in simpler sub problems by using brackets, by using brackets code readability will increase

Comment: @AjayA do you realize that your "*found the answer*" is exactly what I suggested...

Comment: @NikhilBelure Got you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you put anything under the if statement?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3];
list2 = [4, 5, 6];

element = 1;
if element in list1 and element not in list2:
    print("Hello world");
```

Comment: Yeah got you previously I made a syntax error.