# Python NLP processing if statement not in stop words list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I'm working with NLP `spacy` library and I created a function to return a list of token from a text.

```
import spacy    
def preprocess_text_spacy(text):
    stop_words = ["a", "the", "is", "are"]
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    tokens = set()
    doc = nlp(text)
    for word in doc:
        if word.is_currency:
            tokens.add(word.lower_)
        elif len(word.lower_) == 1:
            if word.is_digit and float(word.text) == 0:
                tokens.add(word.text)
        elif not word.is_punct and not word.is_space and not word.is_quote and not word.is_bracket and not in stop_words:
            tokens.add(word.lower_)
    return list(tokens)
```

This function is not correct because removing stop words not working.
Everything is ok only if I delete the last condition `and not in stop_words`.

How to upgrade this function to remove stop words according a defined list in addition to all other condition statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use in and not in operator in a single if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142141/how-can-i-use-in-and-not-in-operator-in-a-single-if-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, there is a small change

at the end of elif put **and str(word) not in stop_words**

```
import spacy    
def preprocess_text_spacy(text):
    stop_words = ["a", "the", "is", "are"]
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    tokens = set()
    doc = nlp(text)
    print(doc)
    for word in doc:
        if word.is_currency:
            tokens.add(word.lower_)
        elif len(word.lower_) == 1:
            if word.is_digit and float(word.text) == 0:
                tokens.add(word.text)
        elif not word.is_punct and not word.is_space and not word.is_quote and not word.is_bracket and str(word) not in stop_words:
            tokens.add(word.lower_)
    return list(tokens)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your condition wrong. Your last `elif` is equivalent to this:

```
condC = not in stop_words
elif condA and condB and not in condC:
    ...
```

If you try to execute this code you will get a syntax error. To check if some element is in some iterable, you need to provide that element at the left side of the keyword `in`. You just have to write `word`:

```
elif condA and condB and ... and str(word) not in stop_words:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add stop_words to the function, which takes a list of stop words as input and then you need then modify the condition for adding words to the token list, to check if the word is in the stop_words list or not

```
def preprocess_text_spacy(text, stop_words):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    tokens = []
    doc = nlp(text)
    for word in doc:
        if word.is_currency:
            tokens.append(word.lower_)
        elif len(word.lower_) == 1:
            if word.is_digit and float(word.text) == 0:
                tokens.append(word.text)
        elif not word.is_punct and not word.is_space and not word.is_quote and not word.is_bracket and word.lower_ not in stop_words:
            tokens.append(word.lower_)
    return tokens
```

Sample:

```
text = "This is a sample text to demonstrate the function."
stop_words = ["a", "the", "is", "are"]
tokens = preprocess_text_spacy(text, stop_words)
print(tokens)
```

Output:

```
['this', 'sample', 'text', 'to', 'demonstrate', 'function']
```